# I have a FileReader class and a FileWriterClass... Can I make a FileReaderAndWriter class with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Long title, but I can't think how to make it any more concise. Same goes for actually asking the question really. Unfortunately, I don't really know the right words to ask the question I want, so I'm hoping if I can describe it, someone will know what I'm trying to ask...

---

Basically, I'm building a game and have various classes for reading and writing various types of file. Config files, saved games, asset packages etc. For the example of asset packages (models, sounds, etc) I have an AssetPackReader class and an AssetPackWriter class, that use an ifstream and ofstream object respectively. Incomplete classes at the moment, just showing the basic theory.

```
class AssetPackWriter
{
protected:
    unsigned int FilesToAddOnCommit;
    std::string * NewFileCommitList;
    AssetPackStruct AssetPackData;
    std::ofstream * AssetPackFileStream;
    bool ChangesSaved;
public:
    AssetPackWriter(std::ofstream * OutputFileStream)
    {
        AssetPackFileStream = OutputFileStream;
        ChangesSaved = false;
    }
    virtual ~AssetPackWriter()
    {
        if(!ChangesSaved) Save();
    }
    void AddFile(std::string FileName);
    virtual void Save(void); //Perform full save
};//The writer only writes new files (overwriting ones that already exist)

class AssetPackReader
{
protected:
    AssetPackStruct AssetPackData;
    std::ifstream * AssetPackFileStream;
public:
    AssetPackReader(std::ifstream * InputFileStream)
    {
        AssetPackFileStream = InputFileStream;
    }
    unsigned long long FindFile(std::string FileNameWithPath);
    void ExtractFile(unsigned long long FileEntry, CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation * OutputSink = 0);
    //First 4 bytes = Folder name index
    //remaining 4 bytes = file name index

    //When the game extracts something, the extract output will be an ArraySink into memory
    //but when invoked from command line, the extract output can either be an existing FileSink, or left blank to create a file on the hard disk of the same name

    void ListContents(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation * OutputSink = 0); //If output is left blank it will be to a string sink which prints to stdout.
};//The reader only reads existing files (read only - no adding new files to an existing archive)
```

---

Now I want to create a class that has the functionality of both. That can:

- create a new package from scratch (like the writer),
- open an already existing package (like the reader),
- add more assets to the package, either

  - without rewriting it all from scratch (which is slower)
  - rewriting it all from scratch (which should make the file faster to read)

A user may prefer a rewrite-from-scratch (FullSave) because not modifying the existing packaged data means a second table of contents needed (which without super optimisation, is far less efficient when it comes to seeking between the tables of contents).

Whilst this FullSave should make reading the file a bit faster (not sure how much by), it takes considerably longer than a FastSave, especially where the existing archive being modified is already quite large.

So, here is my attempt at using multiple inheritance to create such a class that contains both the reading and writing operations of each superclass. This to me sounds more efficient than copying and pasting the functionality of the reader and writer class, but I'm clearly not quite understanding something...

```
class AssetPackageManager: public AssetPackWriter, public AssetPackReader
{
protected:
    std::fstream * AssetPackFileStream;
    bool DefaultFastSave;
public:
    AssetPackageManager(std::fstream * PackageFileStream) : AssetPackWriter(PackageFileStream), AssetPackReader(PackageFileStream)
    {
        DefaultFastSave = true;
    }
    ~AssetPackageManager()
    {
        Save();
    }
    void Save(void); //Overrides inherited function. AssetPackWriter::Save can only perform a FullSave, because it always starts with an empty file.
    //The default for a AssetPackageManager is the FastSave, which only adds new data to the end
    void FullSave(void)
    {
        AssetPackWriter::Save();
        //Rewrites the entire asset package (and all uncommitted changes) from scratch.
    }
    void FastSave(void); //Adds uncommitted changes to the end of the existing file
}; //The packager can write new files, and read (and update) existing files (new files can be added to an existing archive)
```

As you see, I have changed the ifstream and ofstream objects from each of the base classes and replaced with them with the fstream, but something is now telling me that I'm following a dead end.

If the ExtractFile function in the reader class takes an ifstream, can it (when inherited by package manager class) use the fstream?

I thought multiple inheritance was the right way about to go about it due to the fact that:
ifstream inherits from istream
ofstream inherits from ostream
fstream inherits from iostream (which in turn multiply inherits from istream and ostream)

...But I'm just not sure any more, not least because I get errors in the Package manager constructor... It says that the types (ifstream and ofstream versus fstream) are not related, but I thought they were...

```
error C2664: 'AssetPackWriter::AssetPackWriter(std::ofstream *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::fstream *' to 'std::ofstream *'
1> Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

error C2664: 'AssetPackReader::AssetPackReader(std::ifstream *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::fstream *' to 'std::ifstream *'
1> Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: Even when types are related, *pointers* to those types are *not* related.

Comment: If I change the constructor line to: `AssetPackageManager(std::fstream * PackageFileStream) : AssetPackWriter((std::ofstream *)PackageFileStream), AssetPackReader((std::ifstream *)PackageFileStream)` The compile error goes away. Is this the actual solution or is this going to make something really bad happen? I mean it _looks_ fine so far but I can't be too sure

Comment: Random casting can get you into real trouble. Even when it appears to work I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Hmm, more thinking needed then...